# How to redirect stdout to screen and at the same time save to a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to redirect stdout to screen and at the same time save to a variable and running into error `AttributeError: __exit__` at line `with proc.stdout:`,can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

```
...............
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    proc.wait(timeout=time_out) 
except TimeoutExpired as e:
    print e
    proc.kill()
with proc.stdout:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print line
```

Error:-

```
    with proc.stdout:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

**UPDATE:-**

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '),stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
print "Executing %s"%cmd
try:
    proc.wait(timeout=time_out)//HUNG here until timeout kicks-in
except TimeoutExpired as e:
    print e
    proc.kill()
with proc.stdout as stdout:
    for line in stdout:
        print line,
```

Comment: on Linux you could use `tee` command - ie. `ls | tee output.txt`

Comment: I need this on windows

Answer (score 0):

When creating your Popen object you have the stderr set. When you go to open the stdout subprocess can't open it because you have stderr set instead. You can fix this by either adding `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the Popen object args, or by doing `with proc.stderr` instead of `with proc.stderr`. Also, you want to change your with statement a little, like this.

```
with proc.stdout as stdout:
    for line in stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: If I add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` I dont seem to be able to redirect stdout to screen as the cmd runs

Comment: Try deleting the `stderr=subprocess`.PIPE argument.

Comment: that didnt help

Comment: add `,` at the end `print line,`

Comment: Do that by using sys's write. `import sys; sys.stdout.write("Hello")` will print Hello without a newline or return character.

Comment: @PrestonHager - I updated the latest code based on your suggestions,I see that the execution is hung in the `try` block..why is that?how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you make `stdout` a `PIPE` you can just create a loop that reads the pipe and writes it to as many places as you want. Dealing with `stderr` makes the situation a little trickier because you need a background reader for it also. So, create a thread and a utility that writes to multiple files and you are done.

```
import sys
import threading
from StringIO import StringIO
import subprocess as subp
import shlex

def _file_copy_many(fp, *write_to):
    """Copy from one file object to one or more file objects"""
    while True:
        buf = fp.read(65536)
        if not buf:
            return
        for fp in write_to:
            fp.write(buf)

# for test
cmd = "ls -l"

# will hold stdout and stderr
outbuf = StringIO()
errbuf = StringIO()

# run the command and close its stdin
proc = subp.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=subp.PIPE, stdout=subp.PIPE, 
    stderr=subp.PIPE)
proc.stdin.close()

# background thread to write stderr to buffer
stderr_thread = threading.Thread(target=_file_copy_many, 
    args=(proc.stderr, errbuf))
stderr_thread.start()

# write stdout to screen and buffer then wait for program completion
_file_copy_many(proc.stdout, sys.stdout, outbuf)
return_code = proc.wait()

# wait for err thread
stderr_thread.join()

# use buffers
print outbuf.tell(), errbuf.tell()
outbuf.seek(0)
errbuf.seek(0)
```

This is similar to what `subprocess.Popen.communicate` does but writes to more destinations.